# Shopware 6: backwards compatiblity of compiled JS in plugin

Tags: javascript, shopware, shopware6

One of our SW6 plugins comes with fairly basic javascript code. Before shipping it to the SW plugin store, I use the bin/build-frontend.sh script to compile the js assets just as described in the documentation:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-javascript

This has always worked without problems for me. But somewhere in the 6.4.x series, more and more customers reported incompatiblities with their Shopware version. I often have trouble reproducing the error. Most customers report this JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
```

[image: JS Error]

My workaround so far has been to install a demo shop with the Shopware version they are using, install my plugin, compile the JS and ship this version to them - with does not seem right at all. Is there any compatibility table or maps which lets me know if a new Shopware Version breaks bw compatiblity when I compile my JS? Or am I missing something?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this issue is the same like this one: https://github.com/shopware/platform/issues/2420

There was a problem with compiled admin plugins with shopware versions smaller than 6.4.5.0. The compiled code was not compatible with newer shopware versions, but worked with the old ones. When you compile it with a version greater or equal than 6.4.5.0 it will work with all shopware versions.

Maybe this bug also exists for compiled frontend plugins?

**Solution for this was to compile it with a Shopware version greater or equal 6.4.5.0 to be compatible with all versions.**

Answer (score 0):

No way of knowing without having the actual code.

Generally speaking there shouldn't be breaking changes between minor releases, as long as you're using the provided APIs as intended, e.g. as per the documentation. Most certainly breaking changes are never intended outside of new major releases. The more you move outside of the bounds of the intended implementations however, there will be less of a guarantee for that.

If you can reproduce the error, you can to find which line causes the error by [debugging storefront javascript errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raLBeoS7TtE). Then you can provide a sample of the corresponding code.